# How to troubleshoot JRebel?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jrebel

I've an application (some wars) on JBoss 5 but it isn't always getting deployed correctly with JRebel. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. The times JRebel doesn't start I've no clue to why. There are no errors anywhere (in the console, logs, eclipse problems, etc) and the JRebel-logs are very cryptic and give no hints at all. After numerous restarts, rebuilds, eclipse refreshes and publishes to JBoss: it is starting and everything is working fine.

So, my question is, how do I troubleshoot JRebel ? Obvisouly I want to have a more stable development envirionment.

Eclipse Helios with JRebel version 5.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm affiliated to JRebel team. Generally, the [first aid guide](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/resources/documentation/jrebel-first-aid/) is intended for problems like "it doesn't work" or "why it doesn't work". However, from your description I read that it works for you but sometimes you encounter a behavior that you don't expect. For this, it is the best to ask from JRebel support - if you provide the detailed description of your environment and the problem, the guys will be able to provide you with hints of what might be wrong.
Reading JRebel logs on your own doesn't really make sense. It only will make sense to JRebel engineers.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in my case having deployment errors makes JRebel just stop (without any logging about why). I need to do a normal deploy without Jrebel to resolve issues before using JRebel effeciently.

And by the way, JRebel a great product that saves a lot of time.